# Create Morse Code in AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Halo, I'm newbie in AI

I would like to create Morse code and make it as a half circle.
But I tried using dash-line, but it only allowed a few dash and gap, not enough for a Morse code.

Comment: There are [morse code fonts](https://www.myfonts.com/search/morse%20code)... you *could use one of them with type on a path. (assuming $6-$10 at the link is an option. I'm sure you could find some free if you search.)

Answer (score 4):

You could use *Type on a Path Tool* on any path and write the dots and lines with *middle dots* and *dashes*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method. There may be others.

Using a horizontal guide, draw some lines for the dashes. Apply a thick stroke, and rounded end caps.  To get the dots, just draw a line and move the end anchor so it's in the same place as the start anchor.

When you have completed your line of Morse code, select it and click and drag into the brushes panel, and make it an "Art Brush"

Draw a circle, apply the brush you made, and select and delete one of the anchors of the circle.

[image]